# Derivative of $x\arctan x$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives

I have the following derivative:
$$\frac d{dx}x\arctan x$$
I'm unsure of how to solve this derivative; obviously it's a product rule, however is it in a similar vein to finding the derivative of arcsin? Below is my rough idea attempt:
$$y=\arctan x\quad\therefore\tan y=x$$
$$\frac d{dx}\tan y=\frac d{dx}x$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}?=1$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac1?$$
Where do I go from here? How do I find $?$ without relying on some "common derivative" knowledge?

Thank you!

Comment: You product rule and inverse function rule.

Comment: So you understand how you use the product rule, correct?  Your question is really about the derivative of inverse tangent?  It looks like you need to know the derivative of tangent.  Can you find that?

Comment: Namely $$(uv)^\prime = u^\prime v + v^\prime u$$ and $${dy \over dx}\cdot {dx \over dy}= 1$$.

Comment: See here: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-01sc-single-variable-calculus-fall-2010/1.-differentiation/part-b-implicit-differentiation-and-inverse-functions/session-15-implicit-differentiation-and-inverse-functions/MIT18_01SCF10_Ses15b.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the help, yes my issue is finding the derivative of arctan as I don't know where to go after deriving tan (which is sec^2 I've found out from help here!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to go through the process of "$y = \arctan x$ therefore $\tan y = x$ and..." if you already know the following:
$$ \frac d{dx} \arctan x = \frac1{x^2+1}$$

So, you can just use the product rule:
$$ \frac d{dx} \left[f(x)g(x)\right] = f'(x) g(x) + f(x)g'(x)$$
with $f(x) = x$ and $g(x) = \arctan x$.

---

If you don't know that $\dfrac d{dx} \arctan x = \dfrac1{x^2+1}$, then you are on the right track.

$y = \arctan x$, so $x = \tan y$, and then you can differentiate both sides with respect to $x$, making sure to use the chain rule on the right-hand side:
\begin{align*}
  x &= \tan y\\
  \frac d{dx} x &= \frac d{dx} \tan y\\
  1 &= (\sec^2 y) \cdot \frac{dy}{dx}\\
  \frac1{\sec^2 y} &= \frac{dy}{dx}
\end{align*}

Now you just need to express $\sec^2 y$ in terms of $x$.  I'll leave that part to you, but here's how to get started:  Draw a right triangle and label one of the acute angles and the corresponding sides accordingly so that the picture shows $x = \tan y$.  It may be easier to think of it as $\tan y = \dfrac x1 = \dfrac{\text{opposite}}{\text{adjacent}}$.

Comment: Hard to tell, but based on the “?” in the question I think the OP's real confusion is addressed by the second part of your answer.  I would recommend putting that first.